# Query with parameter in Node js return null record set

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I have this query in Node JS with MSSQL driver for sql server:

```
public getDataParameterFirst(SerialNumber, Sid, OreDa, OreA, MinutiDa, MinutiA)
{

    return runDb(cnn => cnn.query `SELECT * FROM activeTelemetry.tbl_EHStage WHERE SerialNumber = ${SerialNumber} AND Sid = ${Sid}
                                                    AND Day = DATEPART(day, getutcdate()) AND Month = DATEPART(month, getutcdate()) 
                                                    AND Year = DATEPART(year, getutcdate()) AND Hour >= ${OreDa} AND Hour < ${OreA} AND Minute >= ${MinutiA} AND Minute < ${MinutiDa}`
        .then( result => { console.dir(result); return result.recordset})

    );
}
```

The query return:

```
 { recordsets: [ [] ],
 recordset: [],
 output: {},
 rowsAffected: [ 0 ] }
```

If a delete

```
AND Minute >= ${MinutiA} AND Minute < ${MinutiDa}
```

The query works.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have an error when it does not work? Or it works and does not return values?

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. I have no error, but in SQL managment studio the query works.. this is really strange

Comment: I would find the exact values of MinutiDa, MinutiA. Then try direct query on the DB. If it works, then you are supplying wrong data format for it.

Comment: I add console.log before execute query and all of value are correct

Comment: Grab the query string form your code, I mean the value it holds. And run it against the DB in your editor. that should give you some light.

Comment: The query work on my DB editor, for this reason it is very strange that not work with node js